# JavaScript mandatory based on selection Selection List

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a java script what will make comment field (textarea) as  mandatory when you will select a selection list , for now I just make a required icon next to comment code below and stuck on it code bellow.

Thank in advice for all help

Code what I Wrote :

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option value="1">AJS.$("#comment-popup").parent().children('label').append('<span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span>');</option>
```

Source Code of my Website :

```
<form action="/jira/rest/tempo-rest/1.0/worklogs/{issueKey}" class="aui tempo-form" data-form-type="" name="tempo-panel-form-popup" method="post">
<div class="form-body" style="max-height: 393px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="issue">
    <input type="hidden" name="use-ISO8061-week-numbers" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="ansidate" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ansienddate" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected-panel" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="analytics-origin-page" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="analytics-origin-view" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="analytics-origin-action" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="startTimeEnabled" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="tracker" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="preSelectedIssue" class="tempoIssueKey" value="AB-5048">
    <input type="hidden" name="planning" value="false">
    <div class="field-group">
        <label for="user-picker-popup">User</label>
        <div class="tempo-pickers">
            <div class="aui-ss medium aui-ss-has-entity-icon" id="user-picker-popup-single-select">
                <input autocomplete="off" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="user-picker-popup-field">
                <div class="aui-list" id="user-picker-popup-suggestions" tabindex="-1"></div><span class="icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu"><span>More</span></span><img class="aui-ss-entity-icon" alt="" src="google.pl"> </div>
            <select id="user-picker-popup" class="plan-user-picker dialog-user-picker aui-ss-select" name="user" data-container-class="medium" data-counter="popup" data-input-text="Jon Smith" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
                <optgroup id="tempo-user-suggested-popup" data-weight="0" label="">
                    <option selected="selected" style="background-image:url(/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=jsmith&amp;avatarId=12927)" value="jsmith">Jon Smith</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group tempo-issue-container">
        <label for="tempo-issue-picker-popup">Issue </label>
        <div class="aui-ss" id="tempo-issue-picker-popup-single-select">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="tempo-issue-picker-popup-field">
            <div class="aui-list" id="tempo-issue-picker-popup-suggestions" tabindex="-1"></div><span class="icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu"><span>More</span></span>
        </div>
        <select id="tempo-issue-picker-popup" class="tempo-issue-picker tempo-picker-all-issues tempo-issue-picker-logwork aui-ss-select" name="issue" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
            <option selected="selected" value="AB-5048">AB-5048 - Holiday - Jon Smith 2016-06-13-2016-06-13</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="tempo-datepicker">
        <div class="field-group tempo-show-period">
            <label for="showPeriod-popup">Period</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="showPeriod-popup" name="showperiod" type="checkbox" value="showperiod" class="showperiod tempo-show-period"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-group datepicker  ">
            <label for="datefield-popup">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="datefield-popup" name="date" size="7" value="2016-06-09" class="text medium-field"> <span id="datefield-trigger-popup" class="aui-icon icon-date tempo-datepicker-trigger" tabindex="0">Select a date</span> </div>
        <div class="field-group enddate datepicker " style="display: none;">
            <label for="enddate-popup">End date</label>
            <input type="text" id="enddate-popup" name="enddate" size="7" value="2016-06-09" class="text medium-field"> <span id="enddate-trigger-popup" class="aui-icon icon-date tempo-datepicker-trigger" tabindex="0">Select a date</span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tempo-timepicker resetable">
        <div class="field-group tempo-worked-hours">
            <label class="timepicker-label" tmp="Work per day" for="time-popup">Worked </label>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="time-popup" name="time" size="3" value="" class="tempo-time text short-field"> </div>
        <div class="remaining-and-billed-hours-container">
            <div class="field-group tempo-logged-work">
                <label for="totalSpent-popup">Logged</label> <span class="totalSpent" id="totalSpent-popup">8h</span> </div>
            <div class="field-group tempo-remaining-estimate" style="clear: left;">
                <label for="remainingEstimate-popup">Remaining estimate </label>
                <input type="hidden" id="remainingEstimateHidden-popup" size="3" maxlength="6" value="">
                <input type="text" id="remainingEstimate-popup" name="remainingEstimate" size="3" maxlength="6" value="" class="validate remaining resetable text short-field"> </div>
            <div class="field-group tempo-original-estimate">
                <label for="originalEstimate-popup">Original estimate</label> <span class="originalEstimate" id="originalEstimate-popup"></span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group resetable">
        <label for="comment-popup">Description</label>
        <textarea id="comment-popup" name="comment" class="tempo-comment textarea resetable"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul id="errors-popup" class="error-list"> </ul>
    <p style="width: 97%; margin: 0 0 10px 0;" id="tempo-logwork-issue-hint" class="hint-container overflow-ellipsis" title="Pressing w also opens this dialog box"> <a class="shortcut-tip-trigger" title="Click to view all shortcuts" href="#" tabindex="-1">Shortcut tip:</a> Pressing <strong>w</strong> also opens this dialog box </p>
</div>
<div class="buttons-container form-footer"> <span id="logwork-spinner" class="aui-icon aui-icon-wait" style="display:none"></span>
    <div class="buttons"><span class="icon throbber"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="issue-add-another" class="tempo-add-another-input" value="Another">
        <label for="issue-add-another" class="tempo-add-another-label"> Log another </label>
        <input type="submit" id="issue-add-button" class="button button-panel-button" accesskey="s" value="Log Work"> <a id="tempo-logwork-issue-cancel" class="cancel" href="/jira/browse/AB-5048?" accesskey="'">Cancel</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you working inside the atlassian product suite.

So You make a html field mandatory you can add the required attribute 
which is workable in all modern browsers except safari I thing please check this

the js(jquery) to add a attribute would be

```
 $('#comment-popup').attr('required', 'required');
```

if it is a AUI-select or AUI input read the docs there 
https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/single-select.html on a select for instance there is a non-empty attribute